# Dimple x2 axis needs position bind to x

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

So this question is all about a secondary X Axis and controls I need to render my chart properly.

I have x, x2, y on a stacked bar chart.

I am trying to get x2 series text stuff positioned at the top (success).

I need the x (order by date) bound to the x2 (seems to work).

Now I need to align x2 directly over x. How does this work?

**Here is the code:**

```
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function svgBuild() {

var data = [
{'yrmo': '01-01-2014', 'prcnt':'24', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'2400'},
{'yrmo': '02-01-2014', 'prcnt':'76', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'2327'},
{'yrmo': '03-01-2014', 'prcnt':'31', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'1900'},
{'yrmo': '04-01-2014', 'prcnt':'69', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'2800'},
{'yrmo': '05-01-2014', 'prcnt':'20', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'1780'},
{'yrmo': '06-01-2014', 'prcnt':'70', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'1800'},
{'yrmo': '07-01-2014', 'prcnt':'28', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'2000'},
{'yrmo': '08-01-2014', 'prcnt':'70', 'halfit' : 'first', 'arbNmbr':'1900'}];

//add property for first half (or put directly in data if possible)
data.forEach(function(row){
   row.halfit = 'first';
});

//create second half
var opposites = data.map(function(row){
    return { "yrmo" : row.yrmo,
        "prcnt": (100 - Number(row.prcnt)),
        "halfit" : "second",
        "arbNmbr" : Number(row.arbNmbr)
       };
});

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 850, 400);

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data.concat(opposites));
    myChart.setBounds(65, 45, 800, 315);

var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "yrmo");
    x.addOrderRule("yrmo", true);

var y = myChart.addPctAxis("y", "prcnt");
var x2 = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "arbNmbr");
    x2.addOrderRule("yrmo", true);

   myChart.addSeries("halfit", dimple.plot.bar);
   myChart.addSeries("arbNmbr", dimple.plot.area, [x2,y]);
   myChart.draw();
}
svgBuild();
</script>
```

[And here is my jsfiddle work in progress.](http://jsfiddle.net/katm9e6s/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the answer.

Take:

myChart.addSeries("arbNmbr", dimple.plot.area, [x2,y]);

and change it to this:

myChart.addSeries("arbNmbr", dimple.plot.area, [x,y]);

That aligned my X series.